# How to scrape a website using puppeteer, including input fields set via $.val()?

Tags: jquery, html, puppeteer

I'm trying to copy the DOM of a website using puppeteer and something along the lines of

```
page = await this.createPage(browser);
page.setContent(await originalPage.content());
```

Unfortunately, the DOM contains input fields whose contents are set using jquery's `val()` (by Backbone.Stickit). As I understand it, `val()` does not modify the DOM attribute `value=""` but the DOM property `.value`.

Currently, this leads to the input fields just being empty when I copy them.

How can I copy the page content so that input field values set via `val()` will actually appear in the copied DOM tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value is set by `jQuery.val` method it's not automatically reflected to `value` property. You could try doing it manually like this for example:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const originalPage = await browser.newPage();

  await originalPage.goto("https://duckduckgo.com/");

  await originalPage.evaluate(() => {
    // Say we have an input with ".value" set
    const $input = jQuery(".js-search-input");
    $input.val("some test value");

    alert(`property value: "${$input[0].value}", attribute value: "${$input.attr("value")}"`);

    // We could run something like this to reflect ".value" property
    // to "value" attribute
    // You can make the selector more specific. Something like ".myForm input, .myForm select ..."
    $("input, select, textarea").each(function() {
      if (this.value) {
        $(this).attr("value", this.value);
      }
    });

      alert(`property value: "${$input[0].value}", attribute value: "${$input.attr("value")}"`);
  });

  const clonedPage = await browser.newPage();
  await clonedPage.setContent(await originalPage.content());
})().catch(console.error);
```

Check out the input value in the cloned page.